# Where does Chesterton mention that popular culture suggests an innate understanding of sexual fidelity

Tags: marriage, cs-lewis, g-k-chesterton

In *Mere Christianity*, in the chapter on Christian Marriage, CS Lewis says,

> "As Chesterton pointed out, those who are in love have a natural
> inclination to bind themselves by promises. Love songs all over the
> world are full of vows of eternal constancy. The Christian law [of marital fidelity] is not forcing upon the passion of love something which s foreign to that passion's own nature......"

I'm looking for the place where Chesterton says this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source, most probably is *A Defence of Rash Vows"* which can be found [here](https://www.chesterton.org/a-defence-of-rash-vows/). Chesterton makes no mention of the appearance of such vows in popular culture, that appears to be Lewis's addition. Here's the relevant text:

> They appear to imagine that the ideal of constancy was a yoke
> mysteriously imposed on mankind by the devil, instead of being, as it
> is, a yoke consistently imposed by all lovers on themselves. They have
> invented a phrase, a phrase that is a black and white contradiction in
> two words — ‘free-love’ — as if a lover ever had been, or ever could
> be, free. It is the nature of love to bind itself...

With thanks to a very knowledgeable and well-read friend.